# How to get <li> tag information (BeautifulSoup Webscraping)?

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup, scrape

I am scraping the information from this page:
https://lawyers.justia.com/lawyer/michael-paul-ehline-85006 .
I am trying to scrape all the information in under the fees section.
What I want is the following information:
**Free Consultation
Yes
Credit Cards Accepted
Visa, Mastercard, American Express
Contingent Fees
In personal injury cases only.
Rates, Retainers and Additional Information
Rates vary on a case by case basis.**

This is what I have tried:

```
for thing in soup.findAll('ul', attrs={"class": "has-no-list-styles"}):
   ul=thing.find('<li>')
   print(ul)
```

but the output is:

```
<li>Intellectual Property</li>
<li>Copyright Law</li>
<li><strong>English</strong></li>
```

Thank you in advance.

UPDATE: I found a solution but it gives me an infinite loop, any suggestions?

```
for o in soup.findAll('div', attrs={"class": "block-wrapper"}):     
    for tag in soup.findAll('div', attrs={"class": "block-wrapper"}):
        if tag.string:
            tag.string.replace_with("")
        for de in o.findAll("li"):
            if de != []:
                de=remove_tags(str(de))
                print (de)
```

Comment: "heading-3 block-title iconed-heading font-w-bold" Use the class Blocks with this div class and proceed to use thing.find() for span and li tags.

Comment: You're calling "soup.findAll" twice one after another try changing the second "soup.findAll" to "o.findAll"

Comment: @Abe it spits out the almost the same exact thing when i change it to o.findAll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req
html = req.get('https://lawyers.justia.com/lawyer/michael-paul-ehline-85006')
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
ul = doc.getElement('ul',attr='class',value='has-no-list-styles',start='class="jicon -large jicon-fee"') # Use class="jicon -large jicon-fee" to locate
print (ul.text)
```

Result:

```
Free ConsultationYesCredit Cards AcceptedVisa, Mastercard, American ExpressContingent FeesIn personal injury cases only.Rates, Retainers and Additional InformationRates vary on a case by case basis.
```

Comment: do you know how to do this without scrapy ?

Comment: @Sophia With SimplifiedDoc, you can use start='class="jicon -large jicon-fee"' to locate. With other libraries, I don't have a good way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this soup. It was inspired by dabinsous answer. All it does is look for the icon that he detailed, then go to its parent's next sibling, and from there grab that siblings text.

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

URL = "https://lawyers.justia.com/lawyer/michael-paul-ehline-85006"
r = requests.get(URL) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
uls = soup.find('span', attrs={"class": "jicon -large jicon-fee"})
print(uls.parent.nextSibling.text)
```

Adjust your scraping to meet that, and see if that helps!

Comment: When I do this I only get : "For Initial Consultations Only"

Comment: Sophia, I've updated my answer after using bits from dabingsou's for some inspiration. Lemme know if it works

Comment: Hm...That's odd, can you explain what is not working?  Also, did you copy the whole snippet or did you edit your code to match?

Comment: Can you look at my update? and I edited it to match

Comment: Try copying and pasting it into a separate file. Also, can you explain what didn't work?